# How do i connect a third party paypal account by using email id and send invoice on behalf

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i am integrating Paypal with our platform for multiple merchants. Here a Merchant just need to enter his Paypal **email Id**, and here i just need to validate his **First Name** and **Last Name** to be matched with Paypal account and the entered names in our platform.

And then i should be able to send invoices On behalf of Merchant from our platform to their customers.

I am looking for below.

> 1) How do i validate Merchant email id with paypal
>
> 2) After validating how do i be able to send Invoices on behalf of
>   Merchants.

FYI, I just find similar setup functionality [here](http://support.stitchlabs.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1511754-paypal---overview?b_id=10321). i would need something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time analyzing, i was able to find that to have above functionality , i have to use [AdaptivePayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) method of Paypal for generating invoice from our side and sending a link for payment and invoice page to customer in mail.

But before doing this i have to validate email id of merchant using  [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) API as mentioned by PP_Punna.

So the following steps are needed to :

1) Validate merchant email Id with first name and last name using [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) API.

2) Generate a PayKey using [AdaptivePayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) method (PAY) by mentioning the receiver email id as Merchant email id which was validated in first step and create url like

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=[PayKey]. and put it under paypal button.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the merchant PayPal account using [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) API:

requestEnvelope.errorLanguage = en_US&emailAddress = teatemail@test.com&&firstName = Firstname&lastName = Lastname&matchCriteria = NAME

After validation, you can get the API call [permissions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/auth-headers/) after that you can run the [invoicing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/) API for sending invoices.